# Go: Passing a return value via an interface{} pointer

Tags: go, interface

I have a function that looks like this:

```
func Foo(result interface{}) error {
     ...
     json.Unmarshal([]byte(some_string), result)
     ...
}
```

Which is called like this:

```
var bar Bar
Foo(&bar)
```

Generally, Foo fetches a string that is then unmarshalled into the result. However, now I need to update it so that Foo sometimes loads data from another source and returns that instead.

```
type Loader func() (interface{})

func Foo(result interface{}, Loader load) error {
     ...
     data := load()
     // result = data ???
     ...
}
```

Is there any way for me to assign this new value to result? I found that I can marshal the data into a string and then unmarshal it into result which works, but I can't imagine that's the best way.

Comment: The first version of Foo does not work. Unmarshal to result, not pointer to result. `json.Unmarshal([]byte(some_string), result)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do,

```
p := result.(*Bar)
*p = data
```

The first line is a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions).

The second assigns `data` to the dereferenced pointer. Assigning a value to a dereferenced pointer changes the value at the referenced address.

Since you don't know the underlying types of `result` or `data` the best you can do is using a type assertion switch.

```
switch v := data.(type) {
case Bar:
    // If 'data' is of type 'Bar'
    p, ok := result.(*Bar)
    if(!ok){
        // This means inputs were bad.
        // 'result' and 'data' should both have the same underlying type.
        fmt.Println("underlying types mismatch")
        break;
    }

    *p = v

case Baz:
    // If 'data' is of type 'Baz'
    // Equivalent of above for 'Baz'
}
```

See **Type Switches** from [switch statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements)

Comment: Only problem is that I don't know the concrete type of result inside of Foo. That's why I'm using interface{}.  Do I need to use reflect to figure that out?

Comment: Bill, sorry I overlooked it. Updated the answer with the best solution I could come up with. I hope you have thought through using this API. Maybe you could change it to just return data instead of assigning it to a pointer?

Comment: I need to pass in a referenced struct for the deserialization case anyways and no matter how I refactor I'm always going to eventually get down to a point where I'm either loading a struct or deserializing a string.  It ends up being something like foo(result interface{}, load Loader) (interface{}, error) which is fine but not as clean as I was hoping for.